# NginX+PHP-FPM setup: Why is this configuration workaround needed to properly set PATH_INFO? [Debian7.4]

Tags: php, nginx

It took several hours to find out how to properly configure `NginX`, but I still think I might have missed something.  Mainly because this perfectly working setup raises more questions than it answers.  Perhaps this even is an `NginX`-bug or something introduced by `Debian` in `Version: 1.2.1-2.2+wheezy2` of `Package: nginx-extras`, I simply do not know.

Please note that my example already is stripped down to the bare minimum (so take this as a starting point) but it still shall contain all necessary current secure fixes.

Please note that I dislike error prone heuristics.  Therefor this runs with `/etc/php/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` set such, that `php-fpm` takes the script directly from `PATH_TRANSLATED` instead of guessing it:

```
php_admin_value[cgi.fix_pathinfo]=0
security.limit_extensions = .php
php_admin_flag[expose_php] = off
```

Here is the `php`-file `/home/tino/www/index.php` which dumps the variables:

```
<?
header("content-type: text/plain");
$a = array("PATH_TRANSLATED", "SCRIPT_FILENAME", "DOCUMENT_URI", "PATH_INFO", "QUERY_STRING" );
foreach ($a as &$v)
  printf("%-15s %s\n", $v, $_SERVER[$v]);
?>
```

## Working NginX configuration

Note that `/home/tino/www` is where my test script lives.  And you possibly want to populate all the other params from `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`.  For example you need

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
```

to populate `PHP_SELF`.

```
server_tokens off;

server {
        listen          80;
        root            /home/tino/www;

        if ($request_uri ~ " ") { return 444; }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                limit_except GET HEAD POST { deny all; }

                fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(.*)$;

                try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

                set             $wtf              $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO         $wtf;
                fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD    $request_method;
                fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME   $request_filename;
                fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI      $document_uri;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
        }
}
```

This gives me following output for `http://example.com/index.php/a.php?b=b.php`

```
PATH_TRANSLATED /home/tino/www/index.php
SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/tino/www/index.php
DOCUMENT_URI    /index.php
PATH_INFO       /a.php
QUERY_STRING    b=b.php
```

This is exactly what I want.  Note that this works for less problematic URIs too, of course.

## The not working config

However, the straight forward configuration **does not work**, and I am really puzzled, why:

```
server_tokens off;

server {
        listen          80;
        root            /home/tino/www;

        if ($request_uri ~ " ") { return 444; }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                limit_except GET HEAD POST { deny all; }

                fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(.*)$;

                try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

                fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD    $request_method;
                fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME   $request_filename;
                fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI      $document_uri;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
        }
}
```

This is the same as above, just the `$wtf` workaround is missing:

```
                set             $wtf              $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO         $wtf;
```

became

```
                fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
```

But this does not work, output for `http://example.com/index.php/a.php?b=b.php` now is:

```
PATH_TRANSLATED /home/tino/www/index.php
SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/tino/www/index.php
DOCUMENT_URI    /index.php
PATH_INFO       
QUERY_STRING    b=b.php
```

As you can see: `PATH_INFO` vanished.  This has nothing to do with `php-fpm`, it's purely an `NginX` thing!

## Insecure config works again

Following configuration, **which opens a major security hole** due to the missing file check, works again:

```
server_tokens off;

server {
        listen          80;
        root            /home/tino/www;

        if ($request_uri ~ " ") { return 444; }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                limit_except GET HEAD POST { deny all; }

                fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(.*)$;

                fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD    $request_method;
                fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME   $request_filename;
                fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI      $document_uri;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
        }
}
```

It has a little bit different outcome on `http://example.com/index.php/a.php?b=b.php` though (`SCRIPT_FILENAME` looks wrong, `DOCUMENT_URI` maybe correct from a different point of view).

```
PATH_TRANSLATED /home/tino/www/index.php
SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/tino/www/index.php/a.php
DOCUMENT_URI    /index.php/a.php
PATH_INFO       /a.php
QUERY_STRING    b=b.php
```

## So please

Apparently `try_files` breaks how `$fastcgi_path_info` is parsed after setting the regexp with `fastcgi_split_path_info`.

So, please, can anybody tell me, if this `$wtf` workaround is indeed the correct solution or do I still have to worry about additional bad sideffects of `try_files`?

Thanks.  (If I missed some important security bit, please comment.)

Comment: Note that the tags are perhaps a bit misleading.  This **question is "how to correctly (and securely) calculate $fastcgi_path_info in NginX"** to stuff it into `PATH_INFO` and **not "how to put this correctly into params such that `fpm` sees it in PATH_INFO correctly"**.  Sorry for that disturbance.

Answer (score 4):

I was working yesterday on setting up my first Nginx server with PHP-FPM and I can have ran into the same issue as yours. Long story short, I wasn't able to properly and securely setup Nginx with all PHP's server variables being properly set. I've finally found a proper setup that I will share with you. However, it would be very nice to hear from a Nginx expert on that subject. Seriously, we ran into really odd issues that should never happen.

## Your setup issues

So, basically, you want a working, secure Nginx+PHP-FPM installation. I mean with "working" that PHP's server variables are properly set and with "secure" that Nginx is protected against known vulnerabilities.

<del>**First** of, I was able to reproduce your configuration and your issues. For some reason, the `try_files` is breaking something. I cannot say why, but you are right when you say that. Replacing the `try_files` directive with the following code seems to fix that issue:</del>

```
if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
    return 404;
}
```

**EDIT:** As discuss below in the comment, the code above [should be avoided](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil). Moreover, the original `try_files` directive is working as expected.

**Second**, I've notice that you didn't include the `fastcgi_params` file, which is responsible to set all the needed (and required) FastCGI's parameters that will be used to set the PHP's server variables. I don't know why you didn't include this file, since every bit of documentation I've read on the web tell us to use that file. Now that the file is included, we need to modify some parameters that are not properly set by default. At the end, we need to add the following directives:

```
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
```

Notice how `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is different as yours. Again, I've read lots of documentation that tell us to use this value (I'll link to those below). You can put the `fastcgi_param` directive either directly in the `fastcgi_params` file or in your `location` section.

**Then**, nothing is working. If I use the same link as yours, I get `No input file specified`. Looking into the log files, I get `Unable to open primary script: /var/www/a.php (No such file or directory)`. I don't know why it's doing that, but all the fastcgi parameters seems to be mix-up.

**Now**, the weirdest part, if I remove this line:

```
fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
```

it's working again, but with the PHP's server variables mix-up. Not only `PATH_TRANSLATED` is not set, `PHP_SELF` and others are not properly set. This is where I have struggle a long time. Fortunately, I've found a solution that seems to fit what we are aiming for.

## Working setup

If we re-enable `cgi.fix_pathinfo` in the PHP configuration, everything works. At first, I though that it was a bad idea to do that. However, I read about the security risks with `cgi.fix_pathinfo` enabled, only to find out that we are already protected against them. With `security.limit_extensions` set to `.php` by default, we are protected against `cgi.fix_pathinfo` issues. Furthermore, the file existance check (the `if` condition we've added previously) protect us even more, by preventing the case where FastCGI tries to interpret other files as PHP.

The final `location` section should look-like this:

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(.*)$;

    try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

## Other toughts

There is one thing nobody talk about, even if they are all doing it differently. I'm talking about the regexes used in the `location` and `fastcgi_split_path_info` directive. Personally, I've choose these one since they are making more sense to me:

```
location ~ ^.+\.php(/|$) { ... }
```

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/?.+)$;
```

I would really like to know the advantages and disadvantages of the other one. Again, it would be very nice to hear from a Nginx expert on that subject.

## Sources

- [Tutorial I've mostly followed](http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample)
- [Other generic tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-debian-7)
- [cgi.fix_pathinfo security issue explained](http://kaiwangchen.com/blog/2012/10/understand-the-cgi-fix_pathinfo-security-issue/)
- [General security advice](https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/)

Comment: Re1: I try to abstain from `if` in `location` if all possible.  So instead `if .. return 404` the recommended way is to use `try_files .. =404`.  Sigh.  See http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Comment: Re2: I did not use include for transparency reasons.  The file provided by NginX cannot be included because it sticks to the CGI spec, which, however, **is not followed by `php-fpm`** (before you answer, first look into the `fpm` source, try it and you will notice I am right).

Comment: Re3: Perhaps you have `php_admin_value[cgi.fix_pathinfo]=1`, in that case it appears that `fpm` follows `CGI` spec.  However it ignores most variables and calculates them, in a lengthy and costly heuristics.  **Obscure heuristics are, by definition, insecure.**  So I will never even consider using such.  With  `php_admin_value[cgi.fix_pathinfo]=0` you have to change the CGI variables, as then `fpm` does plain crap.  Again:  Looking into the source of `fpm` cured me from thinking about something else than `cgi.fix_pathinfo=0`.

Comment: Re4: Also my example is minimal, in that, if you add any other variable, `fpm` completely changes how the variables are parsed.  WTF?  Just look into the `fpm` code and start to weep!  Your answer is helpfup for others to set `PATH_INFO` correctly in `fpm` (Thank you!) but my question is purely on the **NginX side**, because such a bug in NginX makes me worry there might be some additional unknown hidden pitfalls in NginX.

Comment: Re5: RegEx: `/?.+` and `.+` match exactly the same strings.  And `^.+\.php(/|$)` matches something like `/a/.php` like from `http://example.com/a/.php`.  Usually the rule to prohibit "dotfiles" is at the end (it is not shown in my example), so I do not want to have other location rules to match "dotfiles" before.

Comment: @Tino: Thanks a lot for your comments. I've updated my post regarding the `try_files` directive. Also, thanks for your regexes explanation. It's sad to see that PHP-FPM is not CGI compliant (or that we have to fix things ourself to make it compliant). Now, about the issues, I think we should try to get in touch with guys from Nginx and PHP-FPM project. I think we got enough evidence here to say that there is a problem. Do you know how we can get them to read this? Or, what would be the best way to contact them?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea for `NginX`, and no time to find out, too.  Eventually they find out.  About `php`:  I don't think we need to contact them, as you can live with `cgi.fix_pathinfo=0`.  It's non-compliant, but for compatibility reasons we should not change that behavior.  Note that with `cgi.fix_pathinfo=1` it fixes some issues from `apache` (hence the name).  No way to repair that, instead use an NginX setup which violates the CGI spec like `apache` does, that should do the trick (never tested it as I do not want to).

Comment: Please also note that cgi.fix_pathinfo=1 is a security risk even with security.limit_extensions=.php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493207/php-what-are-the-effects-of-cgi-fix-pathinfo-1-in-php-ini-on-a-webserver#comment35880085_16177823

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the following link didn't pop up in this conversation: [try_files & $fastcgi_path_info](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321)

> The ​try_files directive changes URI of a request to the one matched
>   on the file system, and subsequent attempt to split the URI into
>   $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path_info results in empty path info
>   - as there is no path info in the URI after try_files.
>
> I don't think this should be considered as a bug, rather than a
>   feature of how try_files work. It makes try_files not very convenient
>   for use with fastcgi_split_path_info, but there are more than one way
>   to workaround it, including the one provided above.

Mentioned *above* workaround is the one you mentioned in your question.

So, what you have found out is one of the pitfalls of `nginx` and it is not(as of 2016) going to be fixed. Your workaround is perfectly valid and, actually, quoted in the distributed with Debian `nginx` code snippets.